# placing a figcaption directly below an img that is placed absolutely

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a lightbox for a gallery purely out of css and html and looking for a way to display the image when clicked in a lightbox that always displays the whole image regardless of screen size or aspect ratio. this solution does that but the figcaption is stuck at the bottom of the page no matter how tall the page is. how would one tweak this solution to keep the image and the caption visible in all circumstances and fix it to the bottom of the image?

link to the code at codepen.io http://codepen.io/WretchedEraser/pen/QywpYv

```
<section id="portfolio">
    <p>Click or tap an image to enlarge</p>
    <!--thumbnail images-->
    <div>
        <ul id="gallery">
            <li>
                <a href="#img1">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="image of crushed can">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#img2">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="image of Crushed Can project for desn100">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#img3">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="image of narrative line 1">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--lightbox images-->
    <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img1">
        <figure>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="top image of crushed can">
            <figcaption>Trying render with few lines <br>Click or touch anywhere to return</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
    <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img2">
        <figure>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="side view of crushed can" >
            <figcaption>Crushed Can project for desn100 <br>Click or touch anywhere to return</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
    <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img3">
        <figure>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="narrative line page 1">
            <br><figcaption>Narrative line 1 for desn 100 <br>Click or touch anywhere to return</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try removing the `position:absolute;` from both your `img` and `figcaption` and also remove `transform: translateX(-50%);` from the `img` to let the content flow naturally.

**Updated styles:**

```
.lightbox figure img {
    /** Pad the lightbox image */
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 70%;
    margin-top: 2%;
}

.lightbox figure figcaption{
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

See this update [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrxwry)